# Proxy settings in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My application needs to fetch an XML file from the web, as follows:

```
@Bean
public HTTPMetadataProvider metadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    String metadataURL = "http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml";
    final Timer backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
    HTTPMetadataProvider provider = 
            new HTTPMetadataProvider(backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), metadataURL);
    provider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    return provider;
}
```

I'm working by using a filtered network, thus the app is unable to retrieve that file.

There is a way to setup an **HTTP Proxy** (e.g. `myproxy.eu:8080`) in **Spring Boot**?

---

Alternatively, I could retrieve the XML file by using the HTTPS protocol, but I should properly setup the metadata provider in order to support an encrypted connection... How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you can configure in spring boot, HttpClient is not using java variables.

Therefor you need to set the proxy on the httpClient manually:

```
HostConfiguration hostConfig = new HostConfiguration();
hostConfig.setProxyHost(new ProxyHost("your.proxy.host", 8080));
httpClient.setHostConfiguration(hostConfig);
```

Comment: where in spring-boot application does this piece of code goes ?

Comment: Are there options to set proxy properties via the `application.yml` in Spring Boot?