# Spring-Boot behind a network proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, proxy, spring-boot

I am currently implementing an OpenID authentication based on [this](https://github.com/fromi/spring-google-openidconnect) example. Now I am developing behind a network proxy, therefore the server cannot connect to google. The java proxy settings seem to not have any effect. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605372/proxy-settings-in-spring-boot) stackoverflow question, but I cannot figure out where to put the code. How can I configure the proxy for my spring boot container?

thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not sure if this is of any use, but I'm just working through a Spring Boot tutorial currently (https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/) and hit a similar network proxy issue. This was resolved just by providing the JVM arguments

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: You are right I added this and the https parameters inside my IDE and it worked. Coincidentally I figured this out yesterday, but I didn't remember asking this question.

Comment: Perfect !. Worked for me

Comment: If authentication is needed: -Dhttp.proxyUser=<user> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=<password> and for https authentication: -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>

Comment: is there a way to put this in the properties file?

Answer (score 16):

Adding just the two provided arguments didn't work for me.
Full list that did it is this:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=somesite.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=4321 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=somesite.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=4321 -Dhttps.proxySet=true 
-Dhttp.proxySet=true
```

Comment: Zero effect by me.

Comment: `server.use-forwarded-headers=true` in `application.properties` solved the problem. I found your flags irrelevant. However, knowing that the spring boot is maybe too complex compared to its features, maybe for others your solution could help and not mine.

Comment: Did you test it *without* the `proxySet` options? I think that's a nonsense property from a defunct 1997 HotJava bean, though I'd love to know if someone can confirm...

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to make a call to an external service, then try to set proxy to the Client you are using (RestTemplate, etc), as below:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) requestFactory.getHttpClient();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxtserver", port);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could able to solve the problem in two methods

Through JVM args (both http & https)

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=your-http-proxy-host -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=your-https-proxy-host -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

Or Programatically

```
public static void setProxy() {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "your-http-proxy-host");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "your-http-proxy-host");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `server.use-forwarded-headers=true` in `application.properties` solved the problem.

Comment: But this line is when using as reverse proxy, not for outside proxy connection.

Comment: @mafiu Spring boot apps are practically never reverse proxying, typically an apache or an nginx is proxying to them, this apache/nginx is the reverse proxy. I do not understand your comment.

Comment: If the app has no way to access the openid server, then an openid auth is impossible. But typically it can. Maybe it needs to use an outgoing proxy server for that, there are application.properties settings for that. But not this is the hard thing. The hard thing (was in SB 1) to let it accept the X-Forward-* http headers what the rev proxy gives to it.