# Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Azure Stream Binder with a proxy?

Tags: java, spring, azure

I want to connect to the Azure Service Bus Messaging Queue via a Proxy Server. I use the Stream Binder lib in my Spring application

pom.xml:

```
...
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-queue-stream-binder</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
...
```

application.yml

```
...
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.connection-string: Endpoint=sb://examplehost.servicebus.windows.net/...
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination: somedestination
spring.cloud.stream.servicebus.queue.bindings.input.consumer.checkpoint-mode: MANUAL
...
```

I have tried to provide HTTP and SOCKS proxy settings via command line arguments, but this does not seem to work. Is it possible to provide a SOCKS or HTTP Proxy for the connection to "examplehost.servicebus.windows.net" ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about why proxy is in the picture of your scenario since both Azure Spring cloud application and Service bus would be in Azure environment. If by any chance, you meant your app is not Azure hosted and behind a proxy, then you might want to have look at

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/
- [Spring-Boot behind a network proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168113/spring-boot-behind-a-network-proxy)

Comment: Yes, my app would be hosted behind a proxy on a local server. I don't think that a Zuul proxy could be a solution. It would only route traffic between two apps in the same network (or in a setting without firewall/proxy servers). The second link points to a solution by using http proxies, which I tried. I don't think that the spring cloud lib uses the http protocol. My solution was to go back to the 'QueueClient' provided by the azure-servicebus lib, which is able to communicate over http and therefore can be routed via a http proxy. Thank you for your answer. Best regards