# Spring boot proxy configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy

All the connections from my spring boot application which connect to an external service must be routed through a proxy.

I am using [Squidmen](https://squidman.net) for mocking a local proxy with provided services for `127.0.0.1` on port `3333`.

To test if the proxy is working, I can make the following request and see the request in the Squidmen access logs.

```sh
curl -x http://127.0.0.1:3333  -L http://google.ch
```

I found [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168113/spring-boot-behind-a-network-proxy) to configure my spring boot application. So I'm setting my environment variables as follows:

```sh
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
http.proxyPort=3333
http.proxySet=true
https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
https.proxyPort=3333
https.proxySet=true
server.use-forwarded-headers=true
```

Analog to my curl request, this is my java request:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Content-Type"));
```

However, with the specified configuration the request is not forward to the proxy. How can I make sure that these kind of request to external serivces are routed through the proxy.

Comment: Are setting your environment variables correctly ? How do you set them ?

Comment: Yes they are set correctly, I checked. I can retrieve these values with the @Value annotation. I set them in intelliJ in the run configuration where one can set the Environment variables.

Comment: I think they should be VM arguments, not environment variables.