# Enable Socks Proxy for Spring Boot app when running via IntelliJ Idea

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, proxy, socks

I need to develop a Spring Boot application which has external network calls which should get triggered behind a socks proxy. Tried changing IntelliJ Idea's proxy (in Settings -> System Settings -> Http Proxy) but when spring boot app tries to access external API "UnknownHostException" occurs.

Are there any mechanism to configure socks proxy without making any code change?

Comment: You ned to pass VM options to application: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317269/2960034