# Where people put "-Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080" on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, proxy

My Spring Boot application uses RestTemplate to make HTTP requests. But because it works on a corporate network it doesn't have direct access to the internet. It needs to use proxy. I have set a proxy into my IntelliJ but I guess RestTemplate doesn't use IntelliJ's proxy settings. I think I can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317269/233286) method but I have no idea where to put it. My question is where should I set `-Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`?

Comment: How are you running the app?

Comment: @g00se, I click the green "play" button on IntelliJ, and sometimes the green bug button. It is a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click your run target, then "Edit configurations". Under "Modify options" (blue text) click "Add VM options", then add the parameter to the new field that appears.

No, I don't know why they hid it away like that either. It used to be always available, much easier.